# how to call 2 times when data in graphql react?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks

loadGreeting () is not caused by another time when changes props.currentStore

```
  const [loadGreeting, { called, loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(
      GET_COOKIES,
     { context: {
        headers: {
          "x-request-shop-id": props.currentStore ? props.currentStore.id : ""
        },
      }},
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.currentStore.id) {
      loadGreeting();// here it comes a change but does not cause other data props.correntStore
  }
  }, [props.currentStore ]);
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

`useQuery` or `useLazyQuery` is a declarative React Hook. It is not meant to be called in the sense of a classic function to receive data. First, make sure to understand React Hooks or simply not use them for now (90% of questions on Stackoverflow happen because people try to learn too many things at once). The Apollo documentation is very good for the official react-apollo package, which uses render props. This works just as well and once you have understood Apollo Client and Hooks you can go for a little refactoring. So the answers to your questions:

> How do I call useQuery multiple times?

You don't call it multiple times. The component will automatically rerender when the query result is available or gets updated.

> Can I call it whenever I want?

No, hooks can only be called on the top level. Instead, the data is available in your function from the upper scope (closure).

Comment: This does not answer the question asked which is how you can execute the callback that "useLazyQuery" returns multiple times. The question is not about how you can run the hook multiple times. This should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: How are you supposed to understand React Hooks if you don't start using them?

Answer (score 4):

By default, the query uses `cache-first` as fetch policy. So ApolloClient will not query data on the server-side when they are available on the cache.

You should change fetch policy to `cache-and-network` then the ApolloClient will query the data on the server-side, even they are available on the cache or not.

```js
const [loadGreeting, { called, loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(GET_COOKIES, {
  context: {
    headers: {
      'x-request-shop-id': props.currentStore ? props.currentStore.id : ''
    }
  },
  fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network'
});
```